# Downloading AWS S3 bucket contents to on-prem without going through S3 console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am currently accessing the files that I create in an S3 bucket by using the S3 console (web interface)

Is there a way to download the contents of my S3 bucket to my local machine, without using the S3 console and without using access keys given that I have an IAM role assigned?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I do have AWS CLI installed on an EC2 instance, and that has an IAM role assigned to it. The EC2 instance can't seem to "see" my local machine for me to be able to specify a path. So the `cp` command doesn't work. Is there a way to copy files to my local machine?

I am new to this, so I apologize in advance if this is a really silly question.

Comment: You can use AWS CLI. Have you tried that?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an IAM role assigned"? Assigned to _what_?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is assigned to my userid. My application would use that userid to access the S3 bucket

Comment: If the data in Amazon S3 is private, you will need the Access Key and Secret Key associated with your IAM User. The only way to use an IAM Role is to "assume" the role, using your IAM User. So, you would still need the Access Key and Secret Key of your IAM User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install and use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has commands such as `aws s3 cp` that will copy a file to/from Amazon S3, and `aws s3 sync` that can synchronize a whole folder by only copying new/changed files.

Running the AWS CLI requires a set of AWS credentials. When running the AWS CLI on your own computer, you will need credentials from an **IAM User**. You can store them by using the `aws configure` command.

If you are running the AWS CLI on an Amazon EC2 instance, instead of providing credentials you can assign an **IAM Role** to the EC2 instance. This will provide it with credentials to access Amazon S3.

Comment: I apologize, I neglected to mention that I am running AWS CLI on an EC2 instance. And I do have an IAM role assigned to the instance. However, I can't seem to be able to use the `cp` command to copy files to my local machine. I can move/copy files within the filesystems of the EC2 instance.

Comment: You will need to run the AWS CLI on your own computer, not the Amazon EC2 instance. This is because your computer is not accessible from the Internet. You will need to use your own computer to download the files.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank You.